# What is the relation between the scale nodes that includes the pixlate node?

Tags: node-editor, transforms, compositing-nodes

I know that the Pixelate node is used by putting it between 2 scale nodes, but I Don't know which values I should put in the scale node.

I know that when I put the 1st scale = 0.1 the 2nd one become 10,But what about other values,What is the relation between them?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need one scale *before* the [Pixelate node](http://www.blender.org/manual/composite_nodes/types/filter/pixelate.html), and one *after* it.
[image: nodes]

In my nodes, I scale the image down to one tenth of its size (the first *scale* node), pixelate it (the *Pixelate* node), then scale it back up to its original size, with the second *Scale* node.

---

The relation of the scale values is the mathematical inverse. Say you scaled it down by .5, that is just multiplying it by .5, or dividing by 2. So to scale it back up to the same size you need to multiply it by 2.

Here is an example table of the values. The first scale value and then the second scale value.

```
.1      10
.2      5
.3      3.333`
.4      2.5
.5      2
.6      1.6667`
.7      1.42857
.8      1.25
.9      1.111`
```

Note that the strongest pixelated effect is at the top of the table, and the weakest is at the bottom.