# How to get a pixelated image?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, export

I'm trying to make an animated pixel art sprite. I can render it no problem at its normal size settings, but when I set the image size extremely low, it doesn't come out like it should in avi jpeg form. When I render the sprite at its full resolution, it looks like this: [image]

I tried to pixelate it by setting the resolution extremely low, and got this: [image]

That's what I want. I want the image to be pixelated, but when I export the full animation as an avi jpeg video, it completely blurs the image beyond all recognition because it's such a small image. This is what the output looks like: [image]

How do I render / export / format / scale the image such that I will get a sharp, clean pixel animation, with every frame looking like the second picture?

Comment: Avi doesn't support alpha transparency , and jpeg is not lossless and will smooth things out, but i don't think this is the problem..

Comment: Not sure where a setting is or what codecs work with this, but the term I think you are looking for is "interpolation", you want that off.  What program are you viewing the exported animation in?  It could be that program just smooths the image to whatever scale.

Comment: @root Does blender support a format that doesn't compress and supports alpha?

Comment: yes,you can export as h264 and enable `lossless output` , or use avi raw instead of avi jpeg.

Comment: @Sanix25 , no video format supports alpha.

Comment: @root would the best way to add an alpha masked sprite to a program like Unity be to render a series of PNG images instead?

Comment: Make the pixelation on the compostitor so you can render at the desired frame size but with the pixelation effect. Read: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39859/rendering-a-pixelated-image

Comment: related links: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43322/what-is-the-relation-between-the-scale-nodes-that-includes-the-pixlate-node and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24008/how-to-pixelate-a-texture-in-cycles

Comment: related: [What is the relation between the scale nodes that includes the pixlate node?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43323/2217)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *Pixelate* node in the compositor. Go to the *Compositing Screen Layout* or open a *Node Editor* some other way. Make sure the *Compositing Nodes* button is selected.

[image]

Use the following setup. Notice how the left side of the gun is pixelated, but the right side is normal. In the final render, it will all be pixelated. Additionally, see how the both *Scale* node's *X* and *Y* values are equal. Also notice how between them they equal 1 (`0.2 x 5 = 1`). This means that the overall scale of the gun image doesn't change.

[image]

If you so desire, you can copy the node setup straight from the following file (gun not included) (sorry) (it does include an awesome hippie monkey, tho). Lastly, you can read more about the *Pixelate* node [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39859/rendering-a-pixelated-image).

[image]

*Pixelated:*

[image]

*Normal:*

[image]