# Cycles pixel shading

Tags: rendering, node-editor

[image]

I want the rendered result to be pixelated and more cell-shaded like you would see in a 2D game.

Comment: decrease the render resolution, turn down antialiasing

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/55336/245